# How to confirm if the innerText is equal to something?

Tags: javascript

I would like to try and confirm the winner of the game. To do this I was planning on using `document.getElementById('player1').innerText === 0` to check if player 1 score was equal to zero, but I think the syntax is wrong above. How would I check if the innerText is equal to zero?

```
function checkWinner() {
    if (document.getElementById('player1').innerText === 0) {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[1]} you have won the game</p>`;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('player2').innerText === 0) {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[0]} you have won the game</p>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: a string type could not be  strict equal to numeric value... try `document.getElementById('player1').textContent === "0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have said, `innerHTMLL` will be a `String`, but you may convert it to numeric by adding a `+` sign

```
  if (+document.getElementById('player1').innerText === 0) {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[1]} you have won the game</p>`;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just do `=== "0"` instead.

`innerText` can never be a number, it will always be a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing using the `===` ([Strict equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)) operator that will compare operands type too.

The [`Element.innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) will always return a string, not a number.

So your comparison is false:

```
"0" === 0 // false
```

The correct is that you compare against a zero string:

```
function checkWinner() {
    if (document.getElementById('player1').innerText === "0") {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[1]} you have won the game</p>`;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('player2').innerText === "0") {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[0]} you have won the game</p>`;
    }
}
```